# Python selenium issue locating a dropdown element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors, action, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract past one year prices.

[image: Source Image]

Unable to get the XPath for the drop down.

Here's my recent code:

```
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[@title="1 year"]""")
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="chartmenu"]/li/a""")

hoverover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element1).move_to_element(
    element2).click().perform()
```

Where am I wrong here? Please help!

Comment: Looks like an issue with the website.

Comment: can you add html as text not an image

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Wait and check success login, than try to download. Here improved code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'email']").send_keys(************)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'password']").send_keys(*********)
driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()
# wait until success login, by waiting some element on home page

driver.get('https://www.deribit.com/prinx_chart')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='1 year']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-i18n='app.price_index_csv_download']").click()
```

Comment: I get the following: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[data-i18n='app.price_index_csv_download']"}`

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the dropdown element with text as **Download Price Index CSV** you need you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.deribit.com/prinx_chart")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btn-group.btn-group-sm button[title='1 year']"))).click()
  download_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.highcharts-container ")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.dropdown-toggle")))).perform()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#chartmenu a[href*='PrChart'] span[data-i18n*='price_index_csv_download']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: BTC]